# Generalized eigenvectors of AB and BA proof

Tags: linear-algebra, generalized-eigenvector

Let $A \in R^{m\times k}, B\in R^{k \times m}$ be non-square matrices.

A  vector $v \in R^m$ is said to be a **generalized** eigenvector of $AB$ corresponding to $\lambda \neq 0$ if $(AB- \lambda I)^m v = 0$.

I know that if $v$ is an eigenvector of $AB$, then $Bv$ is an eigenvector of $BA$.

However, if $v$ be  any  **generalized** eigenvector of $AB$, i.e., $ (AB- \lambda I)^m v = 0$ then can I say that $Bv$ is a corresponding **generalized** eigenvector of $BA$ ?
That is, is it true that $(BA-\lambda I)^k Bv = 0$ ?

By expanding the binomial series,and pre-multiplying with B, I think am getting the result. However, since generalized eigenvectors include ordinary eigenvectors, am worried if  my purported proof is correct.

Comment: Is there a reason for assuming $\lambda\neq0$?

Comment: Yes,  it ensures Bv is not 0.

Comment: Is there a hole in my proof ? I basically want to use this further and show that the algebraic multiplicity of a nonzero eigenvalue is the same for AB, BA.

Comment: I can't tell whether there is a hole in your proof, because you haven't shown me your proof. You've only told me the general idea behind it. But the result is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $n = \max(k, m)$. We have
$$
(BA - \lambda I)^nBv = \left(\sum_{i = 0}^n \binom ni\lambda^{n-i}(BA)^i\right)Bv\\
= \left(\lambda^nI + \sum_{i = 1}^n\binom ni \lambda^{n-i}B(AB)^{i-1}A\right)Bv\\
= \left(\lambda^n B + \sum_{i = 1}^n\binom ni \lambda^{n-i}B(AB)^{i-1}AB\right)v\\
= B\left(\lambda^nI + \sum_{i = 1}^n\binom ni \lambda^{n-i}(AB)^{i}\right)v\\
= B(AB-\lambda I)^nv = B0 = 0
$$
So yes, indeed, if $v$ is a generalized eigenvector of $AB$ with generalized eigenvalue $\lambda$ and generalized eigenvector $v$, and $Bv\neq 0$, then $Bv$ is a generalized eigenvector of $BA$.

Comment: I think  this is fine if $k > m$, but not enough if case $k < m$, for we do not know if $v$ is then a generaized eigenvector. But if you instead  start with $(BA - \lambda I)^m Bv$, that will work for both cases using the property that the nullspaces are nested for increasing powers and finally become constant once the exponent equals the dimension of the space.

Comment: @me10240 That's true. I should've just used $\max(k, m)$ as the exponent from the start.

Comment: @me10240 Could you please give me a hint for this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4035136/show-that-dim-v-dim-w?noredirect=1#comment8332207_4035136

Comment: @Arthur We can prove that $AB$ and $BA$ have the same eigenvalues but they are order or size is different $AB_{m\times m}$ and $BA_{k\times k}$, so the Jordan normal form of them should be different, am I right? Does that mean, they have the same eigenvalues but multiplicities are different? Then generalized eigenvectors are also different, am I right?

Comment: @Priya They do have different Jordan forms, yes. That's not the question here, though. It's been a while since I wrote this, but I think what I'm saying here is that any _non-zero_ eigenvalue has the same _algebraic_ multiplicity in $AB$ as in $BA$. So the diagonal off the Jordan matrix only differs by the number of zeroes.

Comment: @Arthur I am trying to find an answer to another question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4035136/show-that-dim-v-dim-w
Here I want to show that the equality of the dimension of generalized eigenspaces for $BA$ and $AB$.